# Deserialize XML with UTF-16 encoding in ServiceStack.Text

Tags: character-encoding, servicestack, xml-deserialization, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

I am trying to use ServiceStack.Text to deserialize some XML.

Code:

```cs
var buildEvent = dto.EventXml.FromXml<TfsEventBuildComplete>();
```

The opening xml line is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

ServiceStack fails with the following error:

> The encoding in the declaration 'utf-16' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.

I can see from the source of the Xml Serializer that ServiceStack uses UTF-8.

I am wondering whether ServiceStack.Text can deserialize UTF-16 and if so how?  And if not, why not?

Comment: For what it is worth I faced this same issue and ended up with the same solution as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to hack my way around the issue. I'm not proud of it but....

```cs
var buildEvent = dto.EventXml.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8").FromXml<TfsEventBuildComplete>();
```